# Create a Handler Inside Thread in Android

Tags: java, android, handler, toast, looper

I tried to show the toast from the thread.

```
Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "This is the Toast message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

but throws the exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:Can't create a handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare().
```

How do I solve this problem? I have put the `Looper.myLooper().prepare();` before the `Toast.makeText(....).show();`

When I have done this it doesn't throw the exception but does not show any toast message.

So how do I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your Toast message in onPostExecute of Async Task.. Try this..

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
  Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this,"Your Text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
  if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
    this.dialog.dismiss();
  }
}
```